# Must declare the scalar variable "@chkBeg1"

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that has label and 3 checkboxes with a Edit button, but when i attempt to edit one of the row in my gridview i get this error. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@chkBeg1".
here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView class="gridview" ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
         DataKeyNames="id" SkinID="Professional" Font-Name="Verdana"
                Font-Size="10pt" Cellpadding="4"
            HeaderStyle-BackColor="#109a50"
            HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
                AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#dddddd" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >
            <Columns>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="language" HeaderText="language" 
                    SortExpression="language" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Beginner">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBeg" runat="server" Checked ='<%# GetStatus(Eval("Beginner")) %>' Enabled="False" onclick="CheckBoxCheck(this);" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBeg1" runat="server" Checked='<%# GetStatus(Eval("Beginner")) %>' Enabled="True" onclick="CheckBoxCheck(this);" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Intermediate">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIn" runat="server" Checked ='<%# GetStatus(Eval("Intermediate")) %>' Enabled="False" onclick="CheckBoxCheck(this);" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIn1" runat="server" Checked='<%# GetStatus(Eval("Intermediate")) %>' Enabled="True" onclick="CheckBoxCheck(this);" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Advance">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAd" runat="server" Checked ='<%# GetStatus(Eval("Advance")) %>' Enabled="False" onclick="CheckBoxCheck(this);" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAd1" runat="server" Checked='<%# GetStatus(Eval("Advance")) %>' Enabled="True" onclick="CheckBoxCheck(this);" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
</Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Here's the code for my edit button:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="Data Source=db2.sescor.net;Initial Catalog=SDMS_PORTAL;User ID=sdmsusr;Password=@sdmsusr" 
        ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        SelectCommand="SELECT id, Idno, language, beginner, intermediate, advance FROM [sample_skills]" FilterExpression="Idno = '{0}'"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [sample_skills] SET 
                      [beginner] = @chkBeg1, [intermediate] = @chkIn1,[advance] = @chkAd1
                      WHERE [id] = @id"> 
        <FilterParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="skills" ControlID="label9" PropertyName="Text" />
        </FilterParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must add SqlDataSource UpdateParameters Like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="Data Source=db2.sescor.net;Initial Catalog=SDMS_PORTAL;User ID=sdmsusr;Password=@sdmsusr" 
        ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        SelectCommand="SELECT id, Idno, language, beginner, intermediate, advance FROM [sample_skills]" FilterExpression="Idno = '{0}'"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [sample_skills] SET 
                      [beginner] = @chkBeg1, [intermediate] = @chkIn1,[advance] = @chkAd1
                      WHERE [id] = @id"> 

          <UpdateParameters>
              <asp:ControlParameter Name="chkBeg1" ControlId="CheckBox1" PropertyName="Checked"/>
          </UpdateParameters>


        <FilterParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="skills" ControlID="label9" PropertyName="Text" />
        </FilterParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

For more information about SqlDataSource UpdateParameters check this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updateparameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: why its PropertyName is "Text".. it must contain only True or False because its a checkbox.

Comment: ok,check answer again.i updated.<asp:ControlParameter Name="chkBeg1" ControlId="CheckBox1" PropertyName="Checked"/>